# Msgget fail: function not implemented

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I am writing client-server app on C and I faced with problem:

`msgget() fail: Function not implemented`

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux with Ubuntu 18.04, may this problem appears cause of WSL?

Here is part of my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

 int msg_id;
 msg_id = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
 if (msg_id < 0) {
     perror("msgget");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
```

then I do:
`gcc server.c -o server`
and
`./server`
but then I get this error with msgget

How should I fix my code?

Comment: It sounds like Windows Subsystem for Linux doesn't have msgget. In other words: you can't.

Comment: Run Linux in a VM instead?